# Is there any way to develop the javascript UI controls in UWP application?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am developing UWP application. In my application i want to use javascript html5 based UI components. Is there any way to embed this UI to UWP application.My ui fully developed by javascript, jquery, css,html5. I want to use these components in UWP application

Thanks for any suggestion,

SD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently i have referred the below link and created the app with `javascript` control.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-hello-world-app-js-universal

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> In my application i want to use javascript html5 based UI components. Is there any way to embed this UI to UWP application.

The only way I can think of is to embed [WebView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in your app to include your own html pages. And use [WebView.ScriptNotify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify.aspx) event to communicate with your html controls.

If the most part of your app will be using html 5 controls, I suggest you create a Html/Javascript based UWP App.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion i will check and let u know